# Calculus 2 Integral Question

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, improper-integrals, infinity

I've been trying to resolve a calculus question and seem to be having troubles understanding exactly how to approach it. Some hints are supplied, but they don't exactly seem to help. Thanks to anyone who lends a hand!

> Without evaluating the integral, show that the $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ln(x)}{(x^2+1)}dx = 0$. (HINTS: let $x = \frac{1}{u}$ in order to
>   re-express the integral in terms of u. Compare the two integrals, and
>   recall the basic fact that the only number equal to its negative is
>   zero.)

Comment: If we decide not to worry about the convergence issue, just do the substitution mechanically, simplifying expressions as much as you can. For no good reason, I prefer to break up the integral at $x=1$, and use the substitution $u=1/x$ to show that the part from $0$ to $1$ is the negative of the part from $1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on how I could do this without integrating them? Thanks!

Comment: The existing answer has some details about the calculation. Perhaps more will be added.

Answer (score 0):

If $x = \frac 1 u$, what is $dx = \frac{dx}{du}  du$? Substitute this expression in. How do the limits of integration change?

What is $\ln(x)$ in terms of $\ln(u)$?

What happens to the denominator if instead of $x^2 + 1$ we write $(\frac 1 u)^2 + 1$, and then simplify?

---

In more detail, the hint says to do the following.  If $x = \frac 1 u$, then $\frac{dx}{du} = -\frac 1{u^2}$, so we can replace $dx$ with $-\frac{1}{u^2}du$ and the limits of integration $x = 0$ and $x = \infty$ with $\lim_{x \to \infty} u = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac 1 x = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} u = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac 1 x = \infty$.

Write $I$ for your original integral. Then, at this stage, we have

$$I = \int_\infty^0 \frac{\ln x}{x^2+1}\left(-\frac 1{u^2}\right)\, du = \int_0^\infty \frac{\ln x}{u^2(x^2+1)}du.$$

Here we've switched the upper and lower limits of integration, picking up an extra minus sign in the process, which cancels with the minus sign from $-1/u^2$.

Since $x = u^{-1}$, we also know $\ln x = \ln u^{-1} = - \ln u$. Let's substitute that in. We get

$$I = \int_0^\infty \frac{-\ln u}{u^2(x^2+1)}dx =  -\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln u}{u^2(x^2+1)}du.$$

The denominator is $x^2 + 1 = (\frac 1 u)^2 + 1 = \frac{1+u^2}{u^2}$. Let's substitute that in:

$$ I = -\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln u}{u^2\frac{1+u^2}{u^2}}du = 
-\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln u}{1+u^2}du.$$

But this last thing is $-I$, so we have $I = -I$. That means $2I = 0$, so $I = 0$.

Comment: Could you help me a little more? I'm having trouble seeing how I can resolve this without integrating the equation. Ps, doesn't the lower limit in this case not exist after substitution?

Comment: The point is that after you do the substitutions I (and the hints) have suggested in the original integral $I$, you should get $-\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(u)}{u^2+1} du$, which is $-I$. But if $-I = I$, then $I = 0$ (add $I$ to both sides, then divide by $2$).

As for your postscript, that seems to bey what Andr\'{e} Nicolas was saying about ignoring convergence issues. Of course, the original upper limit $\infty$ in some sense doesn't "exist" either; we're taking an improper integral. The moral is that as $x$ gets big, $u$ gets closer to $0$, and vice versa.